# Best ways of parsing a URL using C?

Tags: c, url, parsing

I have a URL like this:

```
http://192.168.0.1:8080/servlet/rece
```

I want to parse the URL to get the values:

```
IP: 192.168.0.1
Port: 8080
page:  /servlet/rece
```

How do I do that?

Comment: for windows, use CoInternetParseUrl

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Write a custom parser or use one of the string replace functions to replace the separator ':' and then use `sscanf()`.

Comment: There are many traps to watch so a custom parser seems to me a bad idea.

Comment: @bortzmeye: that doesn't make the suggestion invalid. It's vague reasoning. Also, a custom parser is the most powerful/efficient/dependency free. The sscanf is easier to get wrong.

Comment: how is "write some code that does what you need" an accepted answer?

Answer (score 29):

Personally, I steal the `HTParse.c` module [from the W3C](http://www.w3.org/Library/src/HTParse.html)  (it is used in the [lynx](http://lynx.isc.org/) Web browser, for instance). Then, you can do things like:

```
 strncpy(hostname, HTParse(url, "", PARSE_HOST), size)
```

The important thing about using a well-established and debugged library is that you do not fall into the typical 
traps of URL parsing (many regexps fail when the host is an IP address, for instance, specially an IPv6 one).

Comment: In particular, be aware that with IPv6 there are ambiguous cases if you try to use the colon separator.  e.g. 3ffe:0501::1:2, is that a port of 2, or a full address with your default port. The URL specs have dealt with this, as have the the prewritten libraries.

Comment: Note there is no real ambiguity. The URI standard, RFC 3986, is clear and your example is illegal (you need square brackets).

Comment: Thanks, this is comforting. I was under the mistaken impression that user facing code, like browser address bars, was accepting the addresses without square brackets. A quick tour of some popular browsers reveals this is not the case.

Comment: `HTParse.c` has a number of dependencies, any chance you can explain how you can "steal" this from the project easily?  Maybe back in 2009 it did not ;)

Answer (score 15):

I wrote a simple code using sscanf, which can parse very basic URLs.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    const char text[] = "http://192.168.0.2:8888/servlet/rece";
    char ip[100];
    int port = 80;
    char page[100];
    sscanf(text, "http://%99[^:]:%99d/%99[^\n]", ip, &port, page);
    printf("ip = \"%s\"\n", ip);
    printf("port = \"%d\"\n", port);
    printf("page = \"%s\"\n", page);
    return 0;
}

./urlparse
ip = "192.168.0.2"
port = "8888"
page = "servlet/rece"
```

Comment: What platform is this on? I did not know you could put regexp like [^:] in a sscanf format.

Comment: My platform is: uname -a
Linux ubuntu 2.6.24-21-generic #1 SMP Tue Oct 21 23:43:45 UTC 2008 i686 GNU/Linux

Comment: [^:] is not a regexp in this context, it's merely a special format specifier for sscanf(). It is standard. See for instance this manual page: <http://linux.die.net/man/3/sscanf>.

Comment: The parse had some mistakes when no port number, It con't work well. How can i fix it.

Comment: What does %99 do here? How does it work? Please guide

Answer (score 11):

With a [regular expression](http://www.gnu.org/software/hello/manual/libc/Regular-Expressions.html) if you want the easy way. Otherwise use [FLEX](http://westes.github.io/flex/manual/)/[BISON](http://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/).

You could also use a [URI parsing library](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Indeed, using a library seems the only reasonable thing, since there are many traps (http vs. https, explicit port, encoding in the path, etc).

Comment: Hi, I wrote a BNF for url, like this. URL = "http://" {IP} {PORT}? {PAGE}?
A flex generated a file which parsed the url. But how to fetch the individual parts like IP, PORT and PAGE. from the URL

Answer (score 11):

May be late,... 
what I have used, is - the `http_parser_parse_url()` function and the required macros separated out from [Joyent/HTTP parser](https://github.com/joyent/http-parser) lib - that worked well, `~600`LOC.

Comment: Yep. The node.js HTTP parser lib is great and very well tested for anything that has to do with HTTP requests / responses.

Answer (score 3):

Libcurl now has `curl_url_get()` function that can extract host, path, etc.

Example code: https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/parseurl.html

```
/* extract host name from the parsed URL */ 
uc = curl_url_get(h, CURLUPART_HOST, &host, 0);
if(!uc) {
  printf("Host name: %s\n", host);
  curl_free(host);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

This one has reduced size and worked excellent for me http://draft.scyphus.co.jp/lang/c/url_parser.html . Just two files (*.c, *.h). 
 I had to adapt code [1].

[1]Change all the function calls from http_parsed_url_free(purl) to parsed_url_free(purl)

```
   //Rename the function called
   //http_parsed_url_free(purl);
   parsed_url_free(purl);
```

Comment: @ tremendows : Excellent link. It works like a charm.

Comment: Sadly that excellent code is copyrighted 'all rights reserved', so it should not be used in other than a personal project.

Answer (score 2):

Pure `sscanf()` based solution:

```
//Code
#include <stdio.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
    char *uri = "http://192.168.0.1:8080/servlet/rece"; 
    char ip_addr[12], path[100];
    int port;
    
    int uri_scan_status = sscanf(uri, "%*[^:]%*[:/]%[^:]:%d%s", ip_addr, &port, path);
    
    printf("[info] URI scan status : %d\n", uri_scan_status);
    if( uri_scan_status == 3 )
    {   
        printf("[info] IP Address : '%s'\n", ip_addr);
        printf("[info] Port: '%d'\n", port);
        printf("[info] Path : '%s'\n", path);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

However, keep in mind that this solution is tailor made for `[protocol_name]://[ip_address]:[port][/path]` type of URI's. For understanding more about the components present in the syntax of URI, you can head over to [RFC 3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3).

Now let's breakdown our tailor made format string : `"%*[^:]%*[:/]%[^:]:%d%s"`

- `%*[^:]` helps to ignore the protocol/scheme (eg. http, https, ftp, etc.)

  It basically captures the string from the beginning until it encounters the `:` character for the first time. And since we have used `*` right after the `%` character, therefore the captured string will be ignored.
- `%*[:/]` helps to ignore the separator that sits between the protocol and the IP address, i.e. `://`
- `%[^:]` helps to capture the string present after the separator, until it encounters `:`. And this captured string is nothing but the IP address.
- `:%d` helps to capture the no. sitting right after the `:` character (the one which was encountered during the capturing of IP address). The no. captured over here is basically your port no.
- `%s` as you may know, will help you to capture the remaining string which is nothing but the path of the resource you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This C gist could be useful. It implements a pure C solution with sscanf.

https://github.com/luismartingil/per.scripts/tree/master/c_parse_http_url

It uses

```
// Parsing the tmp_source char*
if (sscanf(tmp_source, "http://%99[^:]:%i/%199[^\n]", ip, &port, page) == 3) { succ_parsing = 1;}
else if (sscanf(tmp_source, "http://%99[^/]/%199[^\n]", ip, page) == 2) { succ_parsing = 1;}
else if (sscanf(tmp_source, "http://%99[^:]:%i[^\n]", ip, &port) == 2) { succ_parsing = 1;}
else if (sscanf(tmp_source, "http://%99[^\n]", ip) == 1) { succ_parsing = 1;}
(...)
```

Comment: third if statement will never be tested, becouse second one has the same meaning, so this could make a problem with port/page

Answer (score 1):

I wrote this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <ctype.h>
typedef struct
{
    const char* protocol = 0;
    const char* site = 0;
    const char* port = 0;
    const char* path = 0;
} URL_INFO;
URL_INFO* split_url(URL_INFO* info, const char* url)
{
    if (!info || !url)
        return NULL;
    info->protocol = strtok(strcpy((char*)malloc(strlen(url)+1), url), "://");
    info->site = strstr(url, "://");
    if (info->site)
    {
        info->site += 3;
        char* site_port_path = strcpy((char*)calloc(1, strlen(info->site) + 1), info->site);
        info->site = strtok(site_port_path, ":");
        info->site = strtok(site_port_path, "/");
    }
    else
    {
        char* site_port_path = strcpy((char*)calloc(1, strlen(url) + 1), url);
        info->site = strtok(site_port_path, ":");
        info->site = strtok(site_port_path, "/");
    }
    char* URL = strcpy((char*)malloc(strlen(url) + 1), url);
    info->port = strstr(URL + 6, ":");
    char* port_path = 0;
    char* port_path_copy = 0;
    if (info->port && isdigit(*(port_path = (char*)info->port + 1)))
    {
        port_path_copy = strcpy((char*)malloc(strlen(port_path) + 1), port_path);
        char * r = strtok(port_path, "/");
        if (r)
            info->port = r;
        else
            info->port = port_path;
    }
    else
        info->port = "80";
    if (port_path_copy)
        info->path = port_path_copy + strlen(info->port ? info->port : "");
    else 
    {
        char* path = strstr(URL + 8, "/");
        info->path = path ? path : "/";
    }
    int r = strcmp(info->protocol, info->site) == 0;
    if (r && info->port == "80")
        info->protocol = "http";
    else if (r)
        info->protocol = "tcp";
    return info;
}
```

**Test**

```
int main()
{
    URL_INFO info;
    split_url(&info, "ftp://192.168.0.1:8080/servlet/rece");
    printf("Protocol: %s\nSite: %s\nPort: %s\nPath: %s\n", info.protocol, info.site, info.port, info.path);
    return 0;
}
```

**Out**

```
Protocol: ftp
Site: 192.168.0.1
Port: 8080
Path: /servlet/rece
```