# How to parse a URL in C?

Tags: c, url, parsing

Im wondering how to parse a url into an URL object(of some kind) in C.
So that I would be able to extract key/val objects from a querystring.

Have looked at:
[Best ways of parsing a URL using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c)

And several other resources, even Google Code, but haven't found anything in my taste..
And no, using sscanf, and regex is not an alternative. Saying, unless I have to write my own parser..

Would be greatful for any tips or help on where I could find this!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c/726645#726645 (note I'm pointing to a specific solution which avoids to write your own parser)

Answer (score 3):

[UriParser](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at wget would be worth it. Download the [source](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/wget/) and look at url_parse function in src/url.c.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Bad idea, this function is 150 LOC. Too complex.

Answer (score 0):

I extracted a the parser from wget:

http://eduardo38.netne.net/url_parse.tar.gz