# URL Query parser: Segmentation Fault on Second Parameter

Tags: c

I am currently writing a parser to parse a URL query, e.g. `key1=value1&key2=value2`. I get the first parameter out, but on the second, it dies. Here is the stripped down code I use:

```
const char *query_str = "key1=&key2=value2"
char *tmp, *value, *key;
int no_of_params = 2, value_str_len;
key = strdup(query_str);
for(; no_of_params > 0; no_of_params--)
{
    tmp = strchr(key, '=');
    printf("Currently at: %s/%s\n", key, tmp);
    *tmp = '\0';
    printf("Currently at: %s/%s\n", key, tmp);
    tmp = tmp + 1;
    value_str_len = tmp - strchr(tmp, '&') + 1;
    value = malloc(value_str_len);
    strncpy(value, tmp, value_str_len - 1);
    value[value_str_len - 1] = '\0';
    printf("Adding Key '%s' and Value '%s'\n", key, value);
    free(value);

    key = strchr(query_str, '&') + 1;
}
```

I hope I have adjusted everything correctly. That is actually part of a larger function, but it should resemble the code I use. Here is the output when running it:

```
Currently at: key1=&key2=value2/=&key2=value2
Currently at: key1/
Adding...
Adding Key 'key1' and Value ''
Currently at: key2=value2/=value2
```

Then happens a segmentation fault. So it's clearly the line `*tmp = '\0'`, but why? (Note that in the actual code, I `flush(stdout)` after every print, so I now it is this line.)

I assume since my previous `printf` worked, that `tmp` is what I expect, but why does this technique only work for the first iteration and not for the second?

Comment: I recommend running this in a debugger. That should reveal exactly where it seg faults and why.

Comment: Also, unless you want the exercise, or are not writing anything that will sit on the open internet, I recommend using proven code for parsing query strings. From a security perspective, it is an extremely critical part of your program. For some library ideas, take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1192434/how-to-parse-a-url-in-c

Comment: @RandallCook: Yes, I have looked at many of them and tried them, but non fit my needs. I have already written it myself for the URL itself. Also it is not as critifcal as you might think, since the input is controlled and the usage in the program limited.

Comment: @javex.. What is the value of `query_str` in your program?

Comment: @Ganesh: You have just solved my problem. It was a leftover value and is actually a `const char *` that gets passed to the function. Make it an answer you I can accept it. I will also add that detail above so your answer will make sense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`query_str` is of type `const char *` and hence, `key = strchr(query_str, '&') + 1;` will fail.

Comment: No, it was the accidental assignment `key = strchr(query_str, '&') + 1;`. Because `query_str` is constant, the assignment must of course fail.

Comment: @javex I had typed this answer before I saw your comment on `query_str`.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to what Ganesh says, I see problems with the line `value_str_len = tmp - strchr(tmp, '&') + 1;`. First, `strchr` should find the ampersand beyond `tmp`, but you subtract that pointer value (which normally would be larger) from `tmp` (which is smaller), potentially leading to a negative length. Second, you don't handle the case where no ampersand is found. Yes, parsing is tricky. Good luck.

Comment: I also share the same observations.

Comment: You were absolutely correct. I fixed this error and now it runs smoothly. Thank you.