# How to parse URLs in C using sscanf()?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, scanf, url-parsing

This is my C code that reads a list of URLs from a file, and tries to separate the various parts of the URL.  This is just rough parsing, I'm not bothered about special cases. I guess there is some fault with the sscanf() statement; when I run this, I get "segmentation FAULT". And moreover, the full url is being assigned to the "proto" string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

# define BAG_SIZE 14

char bag[117][30];

void initbag()
{
strcpy(bag[0],"account");
strcpy(bag[1],"audit");
strcpy(bag[2],"ad");
strcpy(bag[3],"advertising");
strcpy(bag[4],"marketing");
strcpy(bag[5],"application");
strcpy(bag[6],"banking");
strcpy(bag[7],"barter");
strcpy(bag[8],"business");
strcpy(bag[9],"econo");
strcpy(bag[10],"commerce");
strcpy(bag[11],"communication");
strcpy(bag[12],"computer");
strcpy(bag[13],"processing");
}
/*
 other bag[] values will be later copied
*/

void substr(char dest[10],char src[200],int start,int len)
{
int i,j;

for(i=start,j=0;i<start+len;i++,j++)
dest[j]=src[i];
dest[j]='\0';

}

int found(char* word)
{
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<BAG_SIZE;i++)
   if((!strcmp(word,bag[i]))||(strstr(bag[i],word)!=NULL)) return 1;
   return 0;
}

void main()
{
int i,j,k;

char buff[10],fullurl[100];
char proto[5],www[4],host[100],tokens[200],tld[4];
float feature[11];for(i=0;i<11;i++) feature[i]=0;
FILE *furl,*fop;
furl=fopen("bizurls.txt","r");
fop=fopen("urlsvm.txt","w");
initbag();
printf("\nbag initialised");fflush(stdout);

while(!feof(furl))
{
   fscanf(furl,"%s",fullurl);
   printf("%s",fullurl);
   sscanf(fullurl,"%s://%s.%s.%s/%s\n",proto,www,host,tld,tokens);// this line isnt working properly
   printf("2hi");fflush(stdout);
   printf("proto : %s\nwww:%s\nhost :%s\ntld:%s\ntokens:%s\n",proto,www,host,tld,tokens);fflush(stdout);


   for( i=4;i<=8;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<strlen(host)-i+1;j++)
           {
                substr(buff,host,j,i);
                if(found(buff)) feature[i-3]++;

           }
   }
  if((!strcmp(tld,"biz"))||(!strcmp(tld,"org"))||(!strcmp(tld,"com"))||(!strcmp(tld,"jobs")))   
        feature[0]=1;
  else if((!strcmp(tld,"info"))||(!strcmp(tld,"coop"))||(!strcmp(tld,"net")))
        feature[0]=0.5;
  else
    feature[0]=0;


   for( i=4;i<=8;i++)
   {
       for(j=0;j<strlen(tokens)-i+1;j++)
           {
                substr(buff,tokens,j,i);
                if(found(buff)) feature[i+2]++;

           }
   }

/*.biz · .com · .info · .name · .net · .org · .pro
.aero, .coop, .jobs, .travel */

for(i=0;i<11;i++) fprintf(fop," %d:%f",i,feature[i]);
fprintf(fop,"\n");


}
fflush(fop);
fclose(furl);
fclose(fop);
}
```

Comment: Crikey, people have a hard-enough time doing this with a full-powered regex engine. I suspect it will be _very_ difficult with the scanf format string :-)

Comment: You should always check the return value of `*scanf` functions.  As KennyTM mentioned, `sscanf` is the wrong tool for URL scanning.

Comment: Can you post more code? How large are your strings? Which instruction segfaults?

Comment: i've edited to post the whole code..

Comment: Ok, this shows that the segfault is due to proto being only 5 characters big but you are copying a much larger text into it -> buffer overflow. That explains your crash. Otherwise I second to not use sscanf for URL scanning (parsing).

Answer (score 3):

%s in sscanf will only stop when it hits the first white-space character, the end of the string or the specified maximum length. Seeing as an URL has no whitespace, that's the reason why proto becomes fullurl.

For the segmentation fault: as proto can only hold 5 bytes (including the trailing null, so only 4 bytes of data which would not cover e.g. https), putting the full URL into it will cause a buffer overflow / segmentation fault. sscanf is rather problematic in this regards. Documentation requests that each char buffer receiving a %s should be big enough to hold the full string (plus \0).

Answer (score 3):

Many answers here:
[Best ways of parsing a URL using C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c)

Answer (score 1):

It won't work because `proto` would match the whole `fullurl` and the rest will be unmatched. You should use a proper URL parsing function or regex for this.