# Parse a URL in C

Tags: c, string, parsing, url

I am trying to parse several elements of a URL in C.

This is a prototype of a URL:

> ftp://[< name>:< pass>@]< domain>/< url>";

The problem is that certain elements aren't being saved correctly, for example I try to save the **ftp:// in here ftp[6]**.  However, when I print it I get something like this **ftp:/d@**. Which should not even be possible since the array does not have enough space for this.

```
int main()
{

   char ftp[6];
   char *name;
   char *pass;
   char *domain;
   char *url;
   char *var = "ftp://[coiso:pass@]teste/umgrandeurl";
   int x;
   int size_name;
   int size_pass;
   int size_domain;
   int size_url;
   int flag = 0;
   for (x = 0; x < strlen(var); x++) {

      if (x == 6) {
         strncpy(ftp, var, 6);
         if (strcmp(ftp, "ftp://") != 0) {
         }
      }

      if (var[x] == ':' && x > 3) {
         size_name = x - 7;
         name = (char *)malloc(size_name + 1);

         strncpy(name, &var[7], size_name);

      }

      if (var[x] == '@') {
         size_pass = x - (8 + size_name);
         pass = (char *)malloc(size_pass + 1);

         strncpy(pass, &var[8 + size_name], size_pass);

      }

      if (var[x] == '/' && x > 6 && flag == 0) {
         flag = 1;
         size_domain = x - (10 + size_pass + size_name);
         domain = (char *)malloc(size_domain + 1);
         strncpy(domain, &var[10 + size_pass + size_name], size_domain);

      }

      if (x == strlen(var) - 1) {
         size_url = x - (10 + size_pass + size_name + size_domain);
         url = domain = (char *)malloc(size_url + 1);
         strncpy(url, &var[11 + size_pass + size_name + size_domain], size_url);
         printf("%d", size_url);
      }

   }

   return 0;
}
```

EDIT: Well the same thing happens to me in the pass but it isn't because of the null char.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c

Comment: Remember to leave place for null character at the end of a string.

Comment: I sincerely hope this is for homework :) and you are NOT creating a production software with that code.  Meanwhile the entire approach that you have is way way off.. you need to get the notion of strings in C. Serious tutorial on C strings is needed to help you.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of building your own url parser try [UriParse](http://uriparser.sourceforge.net/)

Answer (score 1):

from the man page:

> The strncpy() function is similar, except that at most n bytes of src are copied.  Warning: If there is  no  null  byte  among  the
>          first n bytes of src, the string placed in dest will not be null-terminated

```
size_url=x-(10+size_pass+size_name+size_domain);
url=domain =(char*) malloc( size_url+1);
strncpy(url,&var[11+size_pass+size_name+size_domain],size_url+1);
                                                             ^^
```

... and similar for the other sizes / strncpy()s.