# C beginner: split a string

Tags: c, string, split

I have the following string: `"http://www.google.ie/"`.I want to create a string `"www.google.ie"`

How do I do this in C? Here's what I've tried so far:

```
char* url="http://www.google.ie/";
char* url_stripped=NULL;
char* out=strtok(url,"http://");
while(out){
    out=strtok(0,".");
    url_stripped=out;
    break;
}
printf("%s\n",url_stripped);
```

But it's not working.I also fear that if I have a url containing 'h', 't', 't' or 'p', that things will get messed up.

I also need to be able to stip off "https://" from the beginning.

Comment: try strstr() might work as well :)

Comment: If you want to split at the second slash, why do you tokenize on `.`?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c (Esp. answer by bortzmeyer)

Comment: Aside from everything else mentioned by others, you *must not* pass a pointer to a string literal as the first argument to `strtok`, because `strtok` modifies that string in place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about checking if the string starts with `"http://"` or `"https://"`, and then skip seven or eight characters, then then search for the first `'/'`?

```
char *url="http://www.google.ie/";
char *tmp = url;
char *stripped_url;

if (strncmp(tmp, "http://", 7) == 0 || strncmp(tmp, "https://", 8) == 0)
    tmp += (tmp[4] == 's') ? 8 : 7;  /* Skip over the "http://" or "https://" */

char *slash = strchr(tmp, '/');
if (slash != NULL)
    stripped_url = strndup(tmp, slash - tmp);  /* slash-tmp is the length between start of the string and the slash */
else
    stripped_url = strdup(tmp);

printf("domain name = \"%s\"\n", strupped_url);

free(stripped_url);
```

Answer (score 3):

C library gives you a lot of function to work with!
So, a suggestion to begin with, is to give a look here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/ so you can choose the function that fits your needs..
instead of reinventing the algorithm i suggest to work with you already have!
good work!

Answer (score 1):

You should tokenize using the /

```
char url[]="http://www.google.ie/";
char* url_stripped=strtok(url,"/");
url_stripped=strtok(NULL,"/");
printf("%s\n",url_stripped);
```

Comment: It's the third back slash, so repeat the 2nd to last line if you want to use strrok.

Comment: Your code declares `url_stripped` twice and forgets that there's a double backslash after the colon.

Comment: @gnometorule strtok takes care of the token when it is repeated

Comment: @phresnel if the token is repeated many times at a row, strtok will take care of that

Comment: @Mansuro: That's new to me; must say I find it counter-intuitive. This makes strtok seriously a no-go for many parsing situations as there seems no way of checking how many parts have been skipped (tho I admit there are situtations like this where this behaviour is preferred). After the fix receive a +1 by me.

Answer (score 1):

There are quite a lot of ways to do that actually. You did not really specify much on what the code should do in general. As in, what do you want to isolate in this string:
"http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8387669/c-beginner-split-a-string/"

Anyway, if you just want to lose that "http://" and the last "/", I would suggest using this code:

```
char url[] = "http://www.google.ie/";
    char url_stripped[100];
    sscanf(url, "http://%s", url_stripped);//get new string without the prefix "http://"
    url_stripped[strlen(url_stripped)-1] = '\0';//delete last charactar (replace with null terminator)
    printf("%s\n",url_stripped);
```

The "sscanf" function can get very handy in such situations. It works much like "fscanf" and "scanf", but the input is the string.
As for the line "char url_stripped[100];" make sure you have enough space or use malloc(strlen(url)+1); and free(); when you don't need the string anymore.

Answer (score 1):

> I have the following string: "http://www.google.ie/" I want to create
>   a string "www.google.ie"

You can do this (less code, maximum speed):

```
#define protocol  "http://"
#define host      "www.google.ie"
#define slash     "/"

// "http://www.google.ie/"
printf("Whole string: %s\n", protocol host slash);

// "www.google.ie"
printf("URL only: %s\n", host);
```

Easy, right?

Comment: Thanks, I replaced 'url' by 'host' for the sake of correctness.

Answer (score 1):

A late possible solution:

```
const char* PROTOCOLS[]  = { "http://", "https://", 0 };
char* url_stripped = 0;
const char* protocol;
char* url = *(a_argv + 1);

for (size_t i = 0; 0 != PROTOCOLS[i]; i++)
{
    protocol = strstr(url, PROTOCOLS[i]);
    if (protocol == url) /* Ensure starts with and not elsewhere. */
    {
        const char* first_fwd_slash;
        protocol += strlen(PROTOCOLS[i]);

        first_fwd_slash = strchr(protocol, '/');
        if (0 == first_fwd_slash)
        {
            url_stripped = strdup(protocol);
        }
        else
        {
            const size_t size = first_fwd_slash - protocol + 1;
            url_stripped = malloc(sizeof(char) * size);
            memcpy(url_stripped, protocol, size - 1);
            *(url_stripped + size - 1) = 0;
        }
        break;
    }
    url_stripped = 0;
}

if (0 != url_stripped)
{
    printf("[%s]\n", url_stripped);
    free(url_stripped);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
char* url="http://www.google.ie/";
char* url_stripped;
strcpy(url_stripped,url+7);
printf("%s\n",url_stripped);
```