# Qt or general c++ How to get or detect the host of the <a href="file.html" > in c++

Tags: c++, qt, url, host

i have simple app the gets all the links from web page , im using libexml2 to parse the html 
and extract the html links that are inside the  
and Qt QNetworkAccessManager for the http requests .
now the problem is how to detecte automatcly the host name of the links if i have for example :

```
<a href="thelink.html" >
or 
<a href="../../../thelink.html" >  
or
<a href="../foo/boo/thelink.html" > 
i need to convert it to full host path like :
( just example .. ) 
<a href="http://www.myhost.com/thelink.html" >
or 
<a href="http://www.myhost.com/foo/boo/thelink.html" >  
or
<a href="http://www.myhost.com/m/thelink.html" >
```

is there any way to do it programmatically ? without manually doing string manipulation

if you know perl its called : Return a relative URL if possible
from the : http://search.cpan.org/~rse/lcwa-1.0.0/lib/lwp/lib/URI/URL.pm

$url->rel([$base])

code example that dosnt work ( Qt ) 
http://qt.digia.com/support/

```
QString s("/About-us/");
QString base("http://qt.digia.com");
QString urlForReq;

     if(!s.startsWith("http:"))
     {       
         QString uu = QUrl(s).toString();
         QString   rurl = baseUrl.resolved(QUrl(s)).toString();
         urlForReq = rurl;
     }
```

the urlForReq value is "/About-us/"

Comment: [The algorithm to resolve URLs to an absolute URL](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/urls.html#resolving-urls) is defined by the HTML standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not verified if the algorithm mentioned by @sftrabbit is completely followed by this approach, but you can use [`QUrl::resolved`](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qurl.html#resolved) to convert your relative URLs to absolute URLs:

```
QUrl base("http://www.myhost.com/m/");
qDebug() << base.resolved(QUrl("thelink.html")).toString();
qDebug() << base.resolved(QUrl("../../../thelink.html")).toString();
qDebug() << base.resolved(QUrl("../foo/boo/thelink.html")).toString();
```

prints

```
"http://www.myhost.com/m/thelink.html"
"http://www.myhost.com/thelink.html"
"http://www.myhost.com/foo/boo/thelink.html"
```

---

I can not reproduce the code example from the question which does not work for the OP. The only issue is that the `baseUrl` object is missing in the code. The following [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/)

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QDebug>

int main(int argc, char ** argv) {

    QApplication app( argc, argv );

    QString s("/About-us/");
    QString base("http://qt.digia.com");
    QString urlForReq;
    QUrl baseUrl(base);          // this was missing in the code from the question
    if(!s.startsWith("http:")) {       
        QString uu = QUrl(s).toString();
        QString rurl = baseUrl.resolved(QUrl(s)).toString();
        urlForReq = rurl;
    }
    qDebug() << "urlForReq:" << urlForReq;

    return 0;
}
```

prints

```
urlForReq: "http://qt.digia.com/About-us/"
```

Comment: Do you have some specific case which is not working, and what is actually not working? :)

Comment: well i can't give the real site and info ... how can i test on other public site?
ok i just tryed with the http://qt.digia.com/support/ as in the example

Comment: @user63898: You don't need an actual site, just a syntactically valid URL . Using `ftp://files.example.com/this/doesnt/really/exist` is fine.

Comment: i dont have it , i have the site domain , can i do this with other c++ lib ? maybe uriparser?

Comment: I can not reproduce the issue you added to the question, see my edited answer. I get the expected output `http://qt.digia.com/About-us/`. Anyway, if you are looking for something other than Qt, this posting might help: [Absolute URL from relative path](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8749814/absolute-url-from-relative-path)

Answer (score 1):

You should have the path to the webpage that you downloaded, e.g. `http://www.myhost.com/examples/useless/test.html"`.

Take the directory prefix `prefix = "http://www.myhost.com/examples/useless/"`. Every href that does not start with `/` or `http://` is a relative link, and you get the absolute link using `prefix + link`.

E.g. if link =`../foo/boo/thelink.html`, then result is `http://www.myhost.com/examples/useless/../foo/boo/thelink.html`, which a browser will then translate to `http://www.myhost.com/examples/useless/boo/thelink.html`.