# unknown type name BOOL compile error with Linked Headerfile

Tags: c, linker, boolean

I am using the HTParse.c module for one of my C projects. However when compiling with

```
gcc -o project project.c -lpthread
```

I receive the following compiler errors from within the header file:

```
  In file included from Gserve.c:12:0:
  /usr/local/include/w3c-libwww/HTParse.h:117:8: error: unknown type name ‘BOOL’
  extern BOOL HTURL_isAbsolute (const char * url);
         ^
  /usr/local/include/w3c-libwww/HTParse.h:192:8: error: unknown type    name ‘BOOL’
  extern BOOL HTCleanTelnetString (char * str);
         ^
```

I have read to include stdbool.h with C99 and that C90 does not support the boolean data type. Even after including this header, the errors persist. I have included these headers as follows:

```
 #include<stdbool.h>
 #include<w3c-libwww/HTParse.h>
```

Could something have gone wrong during the install of the library? I didn't see anything suspicious in the when making however I did notice some errors at the end of 'sudo make install'...

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:660: recipe for target 'libapp_2' failed
make[2]: *** [libapp_2] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/w3c-libwww-       5.4.0/Library/Examples'
Makefile:174: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/local/src/w3c-libwww-5.4.0/Library'
Makefile:263: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

I am using **Ubuntu 15.10.**

Do you guys have any Ideas for fixing this up?

Thanks Much!

Comment: "I have read to include stdbool.h with C99 and that C90 does not support the boolean data type" - Well, `BOOL` is from *neither*. It is usually a macro defined as `int` in a *Windows* header, or a compatibility header for compiling on non-Windows platforms. It seems you have *neither*.

Comment: Do you have other #include directives before those quoted? Can you compile a file that consists solely of `#include <w3c-libwww/HTParse.h>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of this compiler error is that `w3c-libwww` defines `BOOL`
in the header `wwwsys.h`, and you are not `#include`ing it or any of
the other `w3c-libwww` headers that already `#include`s it. The library's
API boilerplate is meant to be declared by:

```
#include <w3c-libwww/WWWLib.h>
```

before anything else. Look at the provided Examples either via 
[the online documentation](https://dev.w3.org/libwww/Library/Examples/) or in the `Library/Examples` folder in the package.

Correcting this error, however, will not enable you to compile and link
a program with the library because you have not succeeded in building
and installing the library.

The failure that you noticed from `sudo make install` means that *you have not
installed the library*. But the error in question:

```
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:660: recipe for target 'libapp_2' failed
```

is not an error of installing the library and its headers to their
destination directories: it says that *linkage* of the library has failed.

`make install`, therefore, has attempted to `make` the library, as it will always do as long as library has
not yet been built, and that `make` has failed because the library *cannot be linked*.

When I attempt myself to build [the package](https://www.w3.org/Library/Distribution/),
on Ubuntu 15.10, `./configure` succeeds but `make` fails with:

```
gcc -g -O2 -Wall -o .libs/libapp_2 libapp_2.o  ../src/.libs/libwwwinit.so ../src/.libs/libwwwapp.so ../../Library/src/.libs/libwwwxml.so ../../modules/expat/xmlparse/.libs/libxmlparse.so ../../modules/expat/xmltok/.libs/libxmltok.so ../src/.libs/libwwwhtml.so ../src/.libs/libwwwtelnet.so ../src/.libs/libwwwnews.so ../src/.libs/libwwwhttp.so ../src/.libs/libwwwmime.so ../src/.libs/libwwwgopher.so ../src/.libs/libwwwftp.so ../src/.libs/libwwwdir.so ../src/.libs/libwwwcache.so ../src/.libs/libwwwstream.so ../src/.libs/libwwwfile.so ../src/.libs/libwwwmux.so ../src/.libs/libwwwtrans.so ../src/.libs/libwwwcore.so ../src/.libs/libwwwutils.so -lm ../../modules/md5/.libs/libmd5.so -ldl -Wl,--rpath -Wl,/home/imk/develop/w3c/lib
../src/.libs/libwwwfile.so: undefined reference to `HTDir_addElement'
../src/.libs/libwwwfile.so: undefined reference to `HTDir_free'
../src/.libs/libwwwfile.so: undefined reference to `HTDir_new'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
Makefile:660: recipe for target 'libapp_2' failed
```

No doubt that is what you saw too. You must regard a linkage failure of
a library or executable you are trying to build as not merely "suspicious" but entirely fatal.
Until you link it, you have no library.

Bottom line: This (14 yearold) package is broken on Ubuntu 15.10. There doesn't
seem to be a well-known fix. I suggest you cut your losses.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your response! You definitely cleared up some of my general confusion with libraries in addition to saving me a few more hours of headache. A few questions if you have the time: Previously, I thought that the 'make' instruction was meant to compile the source of the library, why do you keep talking about 'make' causing _linkage_ failure? After going back through my 'make' output, I did in fact notice some compiler **warnings** but none were actual errors. On a different note, would you have any recommendations for parsing a URL in C if this library is not an option for me?

Comment: @Lamar A makefile typically but not necessarily describes to `make` the complete recipe
for constructing an executable from its source code, in terms of
relationships of the form: *if item A is out date with respect to the
items B,C... from which it is made, then re-make it by doing X,Y,Z...*.
This recipe essentially involved *compiling* the source files to
object files, then *linking* the object files with specified or
default libraries to make the executable. If you don't understand the
role of the linker, you are trying to run before you can walk: better research it.

Comment: @Lamar As for an alternative library I can't personally recommend one but
[this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2616011/1362568) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/726122/1362568)
may help.