# Regex URL Capturing Group

Tags: c, regex, capture-group

I'm writing a regex expression and trying to get each part of a URL into it's own capture group for extraction:

- **Protocol** *(http,https)*
- **Sub Domain** *(sub)*
- **Domain** *(domain)*
- **Domain Extension** *(com,net)*
- **Path** *(/path/to/file - this is to be the path to the directory the file is contained in)*
- **URI** *(file name)*
- **URI Extension** *(file extension - js,css,pdf)*

**Sample URLs:**

```
http://domain.com/path1/to/file.js
http://domain.com/path-dash/to-dash/file.js
http://domain.com/path-dash/to-dash/file-name.js
https://sub.domain.com/path/to/file.js
http://sub.domain-dash.net/path/to/file.js
http://sub-dash.domain.com/path/to/file.js
http://sub-dash.domain-dash.com/path/to/file.js
```

What I have so far:

```
/(https?):\/\/(\w+[\-]?\w+)?.?(\w+[\-]?\w+)?/gm
```

**Desired Output:**

- **Group1:** protocol
- **Group2:** sub domain (if exist, or blank if not)
- **Group3:** domain
- **Group4:** domain extension
- **Group5:** directory path
- **Group6:** file name
- **Group7:** file extension

**Question:** How can I get each URL part into it's own *capture group* across all the examples I have listed above?

Comment: what language are you using?

Comment: You may be re-inventing the wheel since most languages provide enough built-in means to parse URLs.

Comment: Better programmers than me (and maybe you) puzzled their head over the exact same question - use eg [**`parse-url()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php) for `PHP` instead. For `C`: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c

Comment: @davidhu2000 language is C.

Comment: @Jan I'm going to be using C (sorry for not tagging it, I'll do it now). But didn't even know about that PHP function but good to know, I do write most my applications in PHP.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I've looked but haven't seen any that handle all the different possible url formats from the list in the example.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I mean I like how the `sscanf()` function works and I'll definitely use it, but I still need the pattern to extract into the capturing groups I have listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use https://regex101.com/ to check the group numbers.

If you **DO** care about the numbers, you can always use "non-capturing groups (?:)

```
(https?):\/\/(?:([\w-]+)\.)?([\w-]+)\.(\w+)((?:\/[\w-]+)*\/)([\w-]+)+\.([\w]+)
```

That Way you'll indeed get

Group 1:    protocol

Group 2.    subdomain

Group 3.    domain

Group 4.    domain extension (TLD)

Group 5.    /path/to/

Group 6.    filename

Group 7.    extension

---

If having extra groups doesn't bother you then with

```
/(https?):\/\/(([\w-]+)\.)?([\w-]+)\.(\w+)((\/[\w-]+)*\/)([\w-]+)+\.([\w]+)/
```

you'll get

Group 1:    protocol

Group 3.    subdomain

Group 4.    domain

Group 5.    Top Level Domain (or as you say domain extension)

Group 6.    /path/to/

Group 8.    filename

Group 9.    extension

Comment: It only matched the 1st URL example, it also didn't return the right parts of the url in the specific capture groups.

Comment: 1. protocol 2. sub 3.domain 4.domain-extension 5.directory path 6. file name 7. file-extension

Comment: also `(com|net)` would work, but what I'm really looking for is a universal way to get the domain-extension so regardless to what is between that (.) and the opening (/) of the path (com,net,co,etc..).

Comment: nice! could you modify it to only return `/path/to/` for the directory path (so removing the file name)

Comment: I already fixed the `(com|net)` you can just replace with `(\w+)` since it will stop on the (\) at the start of the path.

Comment: You sir our a beast, I figured out the last piece I needed, if you want to add this to the answer. `/(https?):\/\/(?:([\w-]+)\.)?([\w-]+)\.(\w+)((?:\/[\w-]+)*\/)([\w-]+)+\.([\w]+)/gm`