# split url into different categories in c programming

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

I have `char *initialurl = "http://example.demo.com:80/demo/path"`

expecting output:

```
char *protocol = "https://"
char *url = "example.demo.com"
char *port = "80"
char *path =  "/demo/path"
```

I tried

```
char *initialurl = "http://example.demo.com:80/demo/path"
char *port = strstr(initialurl, ":");
if(port) {
     port = strtok(port, "/") + 1;
     printf("PORT: %s\n", port);
}
```

Similarly, I am trying to use same char *initialurl to split. By then, memory value of variable changing to "http://example.demo.com".

How can i get path?? Do I need to copy char *initialurl to new variable?

Please suggest. Thank you

Comment: strstr(initialurl, ":") returns the position of colon after http:

Comment: for this purpose it's better to use regex methods, like regex_search , https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/regex/regex_search

Comment: Your algorithm is very poor. Lets imagine `http://example.demo.com/demo/set=:xxx`

Comment: Please explain what is memory management about this.

Comment: you're better off using a library for this, as recommended in the [linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726122/best-ways-of-parsing-a-url-using-c) (just ignore the accepted answer). Your specific code has several issues, not least of which is that you're [modifying string literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/164194/why-do-i-get-a-segmentation-fault-when-writing-to-a-string-initialized-with-cha).